# How to configure htaccess to remove index.php and redirect if error 404

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I currently have a .htccess that redirects to 404.html when a error 404 is received. Now my problem is how to remove index.php in a url. Example http://example.com/test/index.php. I want it to be http://example.com/test.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ 404.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

I am using xampp apache.

Comment: It is not clear to me how the 404 handler and removing the "index.php" from the URL are linked, if I understand correctly what you want is to not change the 404 behavior while allowing people to execute "index.php" when they visit http://example.com/test/?

Comment: I want my .htaccess to redirect to 404.html when error 404 is inititiated and remove the index.php when they visit example.com/test/index.php it should be  example.com/test

Comment: I have done the 404 part, but not the index.php part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should redirect like you are expecting from the test I did
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.php$ $1 [L,QSA]

Here is where you can see the test
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=78711e7e-4d95-5116-8c28-83d0362d3632

Comment: So how can I integrate it to my htaccess, with the 404 redirect

Comment: I would probably try

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.php$ $1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond % {REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ 404.html [L,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html


That handels the redirect first and stops there.
Then I updated the 404 again so it stops there and redirects any query information.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the user to execute "/test/index.php" whenever they access "/test/", probably the easiest way is using [DirectoryIndex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex). Just append this line to your .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This will allow the execution of http://example.com/test/index.php whenever the user accesses http://example.com/test/ - and for any other URL.